# Send a limited/reduced class to frontend

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

**What I want**

I want to send a limited/reduced class/object to frontend (as JSON). I use .NET Core 5.

**What I have**

I have a model class like this:

```
namespace Tasks.Models
{
    public class Resources
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Createdon { get; set; }
        public Guid Userid { get; set; }
        public Guid Taskid { get; set; }
        public int Clicked { get; set; }
        public byte Active { get; set; }
        +++ many more properties
    }
}
```

Now depending on the which controller that calls this model I want to have different "kind" of models. So if the resource is file I maybe want the properties Id,Type,Name. But if the resource is URL I want Id, Url, Name.

I tried setting up a method that "initialized the fields I wanted, but that also returned all properties

```
public static Responses FileResponse()
{
    var response = new Responses()
    {
        Id = new Guid(),
        Name = "",
        Type = "File",
    };

    return response;
}
```

Now, when I call the Resources class or this method I get all properties, and returning it to the view presents all properties, but mostly as null, because I only set the three fields in the method.

What is the recommended way of solving this?

Comment: Why is the `Resources` partial? This class looks like a [God-object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)... Seems you are capturing some global state and putting everything together. It's a bit smelly design. You should separate things i.e. Single-dependency principle.

Comment: Probably because I have done something wrong. I can fix that later, I am reading me up on that kind of stuff now (partial, static,abstract,interface) and so on. But does that affect my problem?

Comment: Well, don't put everything together, unless it's *REALLY* strictly related. And what you are showing doesn't return JSON at all. It's not a [mcve]. You're showing one method that returns a `Response`, which will hold all properties (of course).

Comment: Checked my code now the "partial" bit was just something I added just before I posted the code here. To test it, as I was reading different things on the internett. I remove it from the post.

Comment: If it's going ove rthe wire as json to some remote place that only cares about N properties, you can just return an anonymous type bearing just the props you want

Comment: google ViewModel and DTO (data transfer objects)

Comment: @JHBonarius Well I have a class of resources, because there exists a lot of different resources. So it could be a file resource, url resource, image resource or other. And depending on the kind of resource I want to return the object. With the desired properties. 
Actually returning the object as JSON to the view works fine. It  is just limiting the Resource class I am not able to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the field if it's null instead of showing in json with null value.

```cs
    public class Resources
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        // if null, dont show it in JSON output
        [JsonIgnoreAttribute(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        // if null, dont show it in JSON output
        [JsonIgnoreAttribute(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Createdon { get; set; }
        public Guid Userid { get; set; }
        public Guid Taskid { get; set; }
        public int Clicked { get; set; }
        public byte Active { get; set; }
    }
```

PS: Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/hiMAci

Comment: I ended up with using [JsonIgnoreAttribute(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]. That gave me the result of what I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> It is just limiting the Resource class I am not able to do

Yep, side effect of C# being strongly typed, with object X definitely having properties Y and Z. You need *differently shaped* objects - either full on classes or records - that name the reduced set of properties because the serializer is going to look a tthe object and ser every property it can find.

You could make a new class for every variation - quick and easy with records, and easy to pass around inside your C#:

```
public record FileThing(string Id, string Type, string Name);

//make a new one and return it
new FileThing(someResources.Id, someResources.Type, someResources.Name);
```

Or can consider using an anonymous type if you're literally looking to put a few properties into some json, down a socket to a consuming front end (I can't quite decide what you mean by "view" - it doesn't seem to be an MVC View) that only cares about a few props out of many

> So if the resource is file I maybe want the properties Id,Type,Name. But if the resource is URL I want Id, Url, Name.

```
public ActionResult SomeControllerMethod(){

  if(isFile)
    return Ok(new { someResources.Id, someResources.Type, someResources.Name });
  else if(isUrl)
    return Ok(new { someResources.Id, someResources.Url, someResources.Name });

}
```

Anonymous types are a bit harder to work with because the compiler writes the class for you, so it's tricky to do things like declare return types from methods if the method is returning an AT.. But if you're using it as some fill-in all within one method, such as a "make this and serialize it", they work well..

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is not the right one here. I tend to follow more general OO guidelines in this situation (note, some consider these a bit dated, and other solutions exist. But they are still commonly used)

You write against an interface. So let's see what you want... A guid, type and name. All other deatils aren't important.

```cs
    public interface IResourceDetails
    {
        public Guid Id { get; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public string Type { get;  }
    }
```

And you can have multiple of these interfaces.
You could then implement the interfaces per type. But I would probably combine them in a base class

```cs
    public abstract class ResourceBase : IResourceDetails
    {
        public Guid Id { get; } = new ();

        public string Name { get; init; }

        public string Type { get; }

        public ResourceBase(string type)
        {
            Type = type;
        }
    }
```

Each resource type would have it's own implementation

```cs
    public class FileResource : ResourceBase
    {
        public FileResource() : base("File") { }

        // File-specific properties.
        public string Description { get; init; }
        public DateTime? Createdon { get; init; }
    }
```

The response method then could be made generic and look like this

```cs
        public static IActionResult Response(IResourceDetails resource)
        {
            return Ok(new
            {
                resource.Id,
                resource.Name,
                resource.Type,
            });
        }
```